# Query Tridion page by vanity URL

Tags: tridion

In our application design, we want to introduce the VanityURL concept to the user.  VanityURL will be a custom meta for the page.  The broker api which queries the page by URL does not work anymore as the vanity url is not the one in the PAGE table.  The solution we came up with is to query the page id by using a CustomMetaKeyCriteria and CustomMetaValueCriteria and it worked for us.

I would like to have experts here to evaluate this solution and provide some comments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. I would be cautious about querying for metadata for every page request. You might also want to be careful storing this data as Page Metadata, as you will need to make sure the values are unique accross all pages/URLs in the publication.

To get around the uniqueness issue, you might want to create an event system which checks/saves the values against some sort of index file when pages are saved.

The file may look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VanityURLS PublicationID="tcm:0-33-1">
    <Page ID="tcm:3-24-64">
        <Vanity>/someURL.html</Vanity>
        <Vanity>/someotherURL.html</Vanity>
    </Page>
    <Page ID="tcm:3-25-64">
        <Vanity>/someURL.html</Vanity>
        <Vanity>/someotherURL.html</Vanity>
    </Page>
<VanityURLS>
```

You could then publish that index file periodically and use it to look up the requested URLs, and map them to page URIs. You could then load the pages via their URIs, or if you want top use your existing code, you can then use the linking API to get the URL from the URI. You could then pass the value to the GetPageMetaByURL() method.